# Which South American countries are the most vegetarian-friendly?

Tags: travel, lacto-ovo-vegetarianism

I have heard that a lot of South America is very meat-centric in their attitudes. For example, [this site](http://www.bootsnall.com/articles/09-06/vegetarian-travel-tips-for-south-america.html) talks a bit about it. As it mentions, I'd be totally willing to cook at home while there, but I'm still curious.

**Which South American country (or countries) is the most vegetarian friendly?**

Here, I'm taking "South America" to mean any country south of, but not including Panama. I'm sure many people here have a notion of "vegetarian friendly," but I'm using to mean something along the lines of:

1. Finding a restaurant with veg meals isn't an all-day process.
2. I wouldn't be eating the same meal at every restaurant.
3. Stating I'm vegetarian will be met with casual (dis)interest.

My impression is that it may be Argentina, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Brazilian rice and beans looks vegan. However, restaurants use sausage or bacon. So, you need to make sure!

Comment: Had a great experience in Costa Rica

Comment: @chachan me too! But I've been there so looking for somewhere new

Comment: @Azor-Ahai check https://goo.gl/maps/V8yS2rbCjtK2

Comment: [Please see meta](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/70) about this question.